# jquery text slide effect like in google+ Event

Tags: jquery, animation, google-plus, jquery-effects

I'm searching for an text slide animation plugin for jquery or some tips how to do this by my self. 
The animation I like to use in my own projects is this: 
https://plus.google.com/events/cq5653ic2pdnqmkiti7tt192n34/111697084657487423167
To see which animation I meen, click at the blue arrow. I'm searching for this animation where the text seens to come off the background of the text(or div-box) above.

Do you know if there is already a jquery effect plugin like this?
Or have you some ideas how to realize something like this with jquery or CSS3 Transformation?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the opening effect was created by animating some CSS3 transformation properties. in this example: (from what I see)

```
-webkit-transform: rotateX();
```

To my knowledge there are no jQuery plugins that have that *exact* effect, but [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) will get you pretty close as far as animating those properties.

I also worked up an demo. [View it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/_andrewclarkson/SsBwj/68/) Obviously you would have to incorporate some toggle logic and make it look pretty, but it looks as though the effect isn't *all that hard* to recreate!

Thanks much!